# Relation with multithreading and multicores

Tags: multithreading, openmp, multicore

I have a multithreaded program (xgboost) with openmp running on linux in a multicore (40 cores, redhat) server, but when I try to observe the execution and CPU resources used with "top" command, I only see one core being occupied by my executable program.

Is it the case that Linux will only use one core when executing multithreaded program with openmp? If this is the case, then how is the multithreading implemented actually? Just with one core?

Also, is one core capable of working on several threads or just one thread? In linux by default, is multithreading handled by only one core? I know (not 100 percent sure) that multiprocesses can be handled by several cores.

Answer (score 0):

Is usage at >100% CPU according to top? Press '1' when you are inside top to see usage by CPU.

Comment: It's 99% most of the time.

Comment: Then you are using 1 core. A multi-threaded program should be able to utilize multiple cores, assuming the code is properly parallelized.

Comment: So if the multithreaded program is utilizing multiple cores, should I be able to see multiple processes listed in "top" (with several process IDs)? Based on my case that only one core is running, is it because multithreading failed to run?

Comment: Make sure to get your terminology straight: threads != processes. You should see one process (and thus one process ID) in top using either >100% CPU, or if you have pressed '1' inside top, broken down by processor.

Comment: I see the point. Thank you very much. To confirm, a row in "top" does not necessarily mean that it only utilizes 1  core, it can also be implemented by several cores simultaneously, am I correct? In this case the CPU usage will be larger than 100%, right?

Comment: Top is capable of displaying in both ways. Either a single row with total system CPU usage, or one row per CPU.

Comment: why not check how many thread your program is running? it is possible that you use multicore and the cpu usage is < 100%

Answer (score 0):

using ps -eLf from the command line you can see all processes and their threads (LWP light weight processes in ps terminology).
You can filter irrelevant processes with grep: ps -eLf | grep your_program_name